# Global constants in .h file, linking problems with gcc, works with g++

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I have two .c files and one .h file included from them both. In the .h file, I have declared global constants. When building with gcc, I get linking problems, telling me that the constants are defined twice, even though I have

```
#ifndef __FOO
#define __FOO

const struct foo bar = ...

#endif
```

I get

```
/tmp/ccql6KF1.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `bar'
```

However, compiling the very same code with g++ works perfectly. Is there some differences in the way C and C++ treats global constants declared in .h files? What approach should I consider?

Please note that all objects need to share the memory for the constants, since I have limited resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare the constant in a `.h` file and define it in a single `.c` file:

bar.h:

```
extern const struct foo bar;
```

bar.c:

```
#include "bar.h"

/* do this in a single file */
const struct foo bar = ...;
```

Then include `bar.h` everywhere you want to access `bar`:

something.c:

```
#include "bar.h"

void doSomethingWithBar() {
    struct *foo something = &bar;
    ...
}
```

Edit (by Shahbaz): The reason why this works and your code doesn't work is that when you include a file, the contents of that file are copy pasted in place of #include (this is regardless of the file, you can include anything, including files with .h extension is just a convention). So when you say `const struct foo bar;` in a header file and include it in two files, it's exactly like writing that line in both files, therefore defining the variable in both files and hence the link error.

Your header protection also doesn't work (the

```
#ifndef __BAR_H__
#define __BAR_H__
... header contents
#endif
```

) because each of your source files are compiled separately, therefore when bar.h is included in one file and `__BAR_H__` defined, when the next file is being compiled this definition of `__BAR_H__` is lost.

Comment: Perfect! That works. Why should I use `extern`? It seems to work without as well, as suggested by @Clement.

Comment: GCC magically finds multiple instances and puts them together. However, if you used other compilers like `tcc`, you might get an error.

Comment: `extern` declares the variable without defining it. It tells the compiler that this definition exists in an other file.

Answer (score 2):

You should declare only :

```
const struct foo bar;
```

and assign it a value in a `.c` file.

Comment: That works fine, thanks! As @arnaud suggests, you can use `extern const...` instead. Do you know which one is desirable?

Comment: @Johan I would advice the same as arnaud. If you build a library out of your code, it will then work "as-is".